# Is it legal to trade unlicensed gold ETFs in Germany?

Tags: etf, germany, gold

In Germany, gold ETF aren't licensed because apparently they violate diversification which is required by law (cf. [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gold_als_Kapitalanlage#B%C3%B6rsengehandelte_Goldprodukte) [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B6rsengehandelte_Goldprodukte#Besonderheiten_im_deutschen_Markt) [articles](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDR_Gold_Shares#Zulassung_in_Deutschland) which cite an upper limit of 30 % for a fund).

Thus, as a proxy, some people who seek the (perceived) stability (and negative correlation) of gold turn to gold ETC such as Xetra Gold (ISIN DE000A0S9GB0, [German Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xetra-Gold)), although they are just bearer bonds, i.e. the gold isn't protected funds property in the case of issuer insolvency.

However, when I enter the ISINs of two such gold ETF (i.e. US78463V1070 and CH0139101593) in the order mask of my online broker, it offers me to trade them at German regional exchanges. I haven't tried to place an order that way, thus, such an order might be unconditionally rejected.

Also, online securities information portals such as Onvista also list those ETF on German regional exchanges and list some trading volume for the past month:

- https://www.onvista.de/fonds/handelsplaetze/SPDR-GOLD-SHARES-TRUST-EUR-ACC-Fonds-US78463V1070
- https://www.onvista.de/etf/handelsplaetze/ZKB-Gold-ETF-AA-CHF-Dis-ETF-CH0139101593

How is this possible?

Is it legal to trade such unregistered ETF at a German exchange for the seller/buyer?

Doesn't the participant/exchange get in trouble when they clear those trades?

Comment: If you are able to trade US and CH ETFs in German exchanges, then I would guess... that you can trade US and CH ETFs in German exchanges. Maybe Germany does not allow German firms to issue these ETFs but still allows the ones from other countries to be traded? I have never ever ever heard of any participant getting in trouble for trading something that their broker allowed to be traded because the thing being traded was not legal. If it's not legal the broker should be the one in trouble.